# Why is a**2 != a * a for some floats?

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15

$ type test.py
import random

while True:
    a = random.uniform(0, 1)
    b = a ** 2
    c = a * a
    if b != c:
        print "a = {}".format(a)
        print "a ** 2 = {}".format(b)
        print "a * a = {}".format(c)
        break

$ python test.py
a = 0.145376687586
a ** 2 = 0.0211343812936
a * a = 0.0211343812936
```

I was only able to reproduce this on a Windows build of Python - to be precise: `Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`. On my [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) box installation of Python (`Python 2.7.15 (default, May 1 2018, 20:16:04) [GCC 7.3.1 20180406] on linux2`) the loop does not seem to terminate indicating that the `a**2 = a * a` invariant holds there.

What is going on here? I know that IEEE floats come with a plethora of misconceptions and idiosyncrasies ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), for example, does not answer my question), but I fail to see what part of the specification or what kind of implementation of `**` could possibly allow for this.

To address the duplicate flagging: This is most likely not directly an IEEE floating point math problem and more of a implementation issue of the `**` operator. Therefore, this is not a duplicate of questions which are only asking about floating point issues such as precision or associativity.

Comment: Use `repr` to show more digits so we can see exactly what value it's failing on and how.

Comment: … or, since you're already using `format`, use `{.30}` or something.

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of "Is floating-point math broken".  The OP is asking why `a ** 2` is not implemented as `a * a`.

Comment: Meanwhile, where in the spec do you see that `x ** n` should be equivalent to repeated multiplication if `n` happens to be an integer, much less implemented that way?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Exponentiation isn't an operation IEEE 754 requires to be correctly rounded. Relying on `a**2 == a*a` is just going to lead to pain.

Comment: @user2357112: Regardless of whether IEEE 754 requires exponentiation be correctly rounded (it does recommend it), the nature of floating-point is **not** the cause of the problem OP observes. Floating-point operations are perfectly capable of supporting the identity `a**2 == a*a`. Therefore, if it fails to hold in some implementation, there is a cause other than the nature of floating-point. And I have not suggested OP or anybody else rely on this identity. I have merely stated the cause of the failure is not due to the nature of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Welcome to floating point, where nothing is precise. Seriously. This sort of stuff comes up all the time. We don't need a new question on every application of it. It should surprise us more when anything in floating works precisely the way math suggests.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Python relies on the underlying platform for its floating-point arithmetic. I hypothesize that Python’s `**` operator uses a `pow` implementation (as used in C) (confirmed by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) referring to Python [2.7.15 source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.15/Objects/floatobject.c#L921)).

Generally, `pow` is implemented by using (approximations of) logarithms and exponentials, in part. This is necessary since `pow` supports non-integer arguments. (Of course, this general implementation does not preclude specializations for subsets of its domain.)

Microsoft’s `pow` implementation is notoriously not good. Hence, for `pow(a, 2)`, it may be returning a result not equal to `a*a`.

Comment: You can see the use of C `pow` in `float.__pow__` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.15/Objects/floatobject.c#L921).

Comment: That `float_pow` implementation is of course only for CPython—but if you look into Jython, IronPython, or PyPy, you'll see that they use similar functions in Java, .NET, and RPython.

Comment: I have a hunch that small integer powers are special cased at least on linux, indeed, of `a*a, a**2, math.exp(2*math.log(a))` the first two seem to be equal all the time, while the third often deviates.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: That's not necessarily an indication that integer powers are special cased. On a platform that had perfectly correctly-rounded power, exp and log, you'd expect to see exactly the same results: `math.exp(2 * math.log(a))` will often deviate thanks to the extra rounding error of the intermediate `math.log(a)` value. That error is then potentially magnified by the `exp` call (depending on the value of `a`). A good implementation of `pow` should be doing something more sophisticated than `exp(y*log(x))`.

Answer (score 9):

`a ** 2` uses a *floating point* power function (like the one you can find in the standard C math lib), which is able to elevate any number to any power.

`a * a` is just multiplying *once*, it's more suitable for this case, and not liable to precision errors, (even more true for integers), like `a ** 2` would be.

For floating point `a`, if you want to elevate to a power of, say, 5, by using

```
a * a * a * a * a
```

you'd be better off with `a**5` because repeated multiplication is now liable to floating point accumulation error, and it's much slower.

`a ** b` is more interesting when `b` is large, because it's more efficient, for instance. But the precision may differ because it uses a floating point algorithm.

Comment: `float.__pow__` does not use the `math.pow` function, at least not in CPython. They do, however, both ultimately use the same `pow` function from the C stdlib (after a bunch of pre-checks and conversions that are not identical for the two), which is probably what you should be saying here.

Comment: yep, slightly inaccurate.

Comment: Even a * a can have precision errors if the original uses enough digits.  2.5 * 2.5 would be fine but 2.123456789 * 2.123456789 will have some precision loss.

Comment: @LorenPechtel `2.5*2.5` only works because it's exactly representable in binary with only a few bits. Try `2.2*2.2` (`4.840000000000001`).

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes.  I deliberately picked a value with a short representation in floating point so there would be no precision loss.